# phpmyadmin - Integrity violation

Tags: phpmyadmin, foreign-keys, primary-key

I know this is a simple question but it still happens to me. 
I've read numerous methods to handle this.

The story is: I have 2 tables in database and I'm creating a form.

- Table named **user** contains **user_id and name, email, password**.
- Table named **form** contains **form_id, content and user_id**.

[PROBLEMS]

- Case 1: fk and pk **not the same type**. Nope, I don't think so. I set them all **int, unsigned**
- Case 2: **Data** is **inserted** into table **containing fk** **before** **table containing** **pk**. No away. Because the steps are: I have to log in then I'm allowed to submit a form. So user_id already existed. So this case's never gonna happen.

So please, give me some thoughts to handle this. every help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post some screenshot of the problems? I don't recall seeing either of those error messages in phpMyAdmin and it would be helpful to be able to recreate your situation.

Comment: I've handled this bro. Anw thanks for ur comment :)